# Delete to Last Cell

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening,

do I have to specify the end line of the data to be deleted or is it even easier?

Best wishes

```
   Sub Delete()
       Dim lz AS Long   
            Lz = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
            ' the next line
            Rows(Lz & ":1048576").Delete


   End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, you must clarify what you really want to accomplish. Do you want to delete the last row with data? Otherwise, it is at least strange to delete after the last row with data... Then, do you really want to delete the row, or only clear its contents?

Comment: I want to delete everything after the last line.
Because there is only formatting underneath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub ClearAll()
       Dim lz As Long
            lz = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row + 1
            Range(Cells(lz, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Clear
End Sub
```

No need to delete anything, if you need to clear. The above code will clear everything, starting from the first empty row...

Comment: Hello Fanduru,

thanks for this tip. in some cells (column A - xfd) there are tabs or _ spaces. so I wanted to delete it. It does not work with the Clear content.

Comment: @Can Ulucan : It must do the job by only clearing. Try the updated code, please. It looks that `UsedRange.Columns` did not do what I supposed it must does... It clears everything. Merge cells inclusively...